# How to connect dart app with Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, dart, heroku

I am developing a simple dart server. I deployed it on Heroku, but I can't figure out, how I can connect my app with Heroku Postgres. I know that the needed Postgres infos are saved in an environmental variable, but I don't know how I can access this via my running app.
Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/Platform-class.html

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

void main() {
  Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
  print(envVars['DATABASE_URL']);
}
```